# Problems with Horizontal Scroll Menu

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I am facing problems with horizontal scrolling menu into my website.

I used the code of [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_menu_hor_scroll) for this navbar. The problem is that it does not applies to the nav menu. Therefore, the scroll effect is missing both on **PC** and **Mobile** version.

[Link to my website](http://novostroyka.shahar.uz/developer/FDG/)

Here is how nav menu looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `display: block` style from your `.active` class.
The scrollbar does not appear because it fits inside without the need of a scrollbar. Set a `max-width` style to the parent element to get the scrollbar